# Django: HttpResponse in RetrieveAPIView giving an AttributeError

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, httpresponse

I'm trying to create API for liking a post. This works for liking a post
but I get error when adding the return `HttpResponse/Response` statements gives an error:

```
AttributeError at /api/posts/like/4/
'HttpResponse' object has no attribute 'model'
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/posts/like/4/
Django Version: 2.0.7
```

#### views.py

```
class LikeDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = self.request.user
        post_id = self.kwargs['pk']
        like = Like(post=Post.objects.get(id=post_id), user=user)
        user_like = Like.objects.filter(post=post_id, user=user)

        if user_like.exists():
            user_like.delete()
            content = {'message': 'unliked'}
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
         else:
            like.save()
            content = {'message': 'like'}
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

#### urls.py

```
url(r'^like/(?P<pk>.+)/$',LikeDetailAPIView.as_view(), name='likeapi'),
```

What I am intending to do is return a success message.

#### serializer.py

```
class LikeListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
       model = Like
       fields = [
            'user',
            'post',
            'time',
       ]
```

Any links that I can refer to?

Comment: Your `get_queryset` returns a `Response`?

Comment: Furthermore it looks like your GET request will introduce side-effects, which is against the principles of what a GET request is supposed to do.

Comment: just need to return a message, not necessarily a **Response**, was just trying out things as to get a message.

Comment: but the `get_queryset` should - like the name suggests - return a `QuerySet`, you can override the `.get`, `.post`, etc. Furthermore you are never supposed to perform actions with side-effects in a GET request anyway.

Comment: Changed from `GET` to `POST`, re-wrote the function, used `def post`, now works,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From the official [DRF doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_querysetself),

> **`get_queryset(self)`** method returns the `queryset` that should be used for list views, and that
>   should be used as the base for lookups in **`detail views`**. Defaults
>   to returning the queryset specified by the `queryset` attribute.

From your comments, I understood that, you need to show some response when you access the API (*detail-view*).

Since you are using **`RetrieveAPIView`** class, you have to override **`retrieve()`** method, as

```
from rest_framework.generics import RetrieveAPIView


class LikeDetailAPIView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Like.objects.filter(post=self.kwargs['pk'], user=self.request.user)

    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.get_queryset().exists():
            self.get_queryset().delete()
            content = {'message': 'unliked'}
            return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
        like = Like(post=Post.objects.get(id=post_id), user=user)
        like.save()
        content = {'message': 'like'}
        return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

Now you can access the endpoint, **`/api/posts/like/4/`** by **HTTP GET** method